# data not loaded fully in HTML

Tags: html, vb6, web-scraping

I am trying to create a **scraper** using vb6, my technique is to search the html page with get between 2 text function.

the function is tested and working correctly for all the sites, except a new site that I tried to use the same technique with it and failed.

The problem is the html is not showing the data, piece of the html as below:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" class="label">Company Name:</td>
<td><span class="search-custom" id="synopsisDetailsOppNum"></span></td>
</tr>
```

the value should appear between the span tag above, but it's not appeared inside the HTML as above code.

The website is using javascript to manage the data.

I have tried also to use wait function, may the data appear with the HTML, but failed too.

Is there any solution to get the value, even with vb.net as I can update my code

Comment: Check selenium for visual basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that website is using JavaScript to add data to the webpage and such manipulation will not show up on the page source

**The follwoing is quoted from JavaScript & jQuery: The Missing Manual  by David Sawyer McFarland**

> One problem with using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM by adding,
> changing, deleting, and rearranging HTML code is that it’s hard to
> figure out what the HTML of a page looks like when JavaScript is
> finished. For example, the View Source command available in every
> browser only shows the web page file as it was downloaded from the web
> server. In other words, you see the HTML before it was changed by
> JavaScript, which can make it very hard to figure out if the
> JavaScript you’re writing is really producing the HTML you’re after.
> For example, if you could see what the HTML of your page looks like
> after your JavaScript adds 10 error messages to a form page, or after
> your JavaScript program creates an elaborate pop-up dialog box
> complete with text and form fields, it would be a lot easier to see if
> you’re ending up with the HTML you want. Fortunately, most major
> browsers offer a set of developer tools that let you view the rendered
> HTML—the HTML that the browser displays after JavaScript has done its
> magic. Usually the tools appear as a pane at the bottom of the browser
> window, below the web page. Different tabs let you access JavaScript
> code, HTML, CSS, and other useful resources. The exact name of the tab
> and method for turning on the tools panel varies from browser to
> browser: • In Firefox, install the Firebug plug-in (discussed on page
> 477). Open a page with the JavaScript code you wish to see and open
> Firebug (Tools→Firebug→Open Firebug). Click the HTML tab in the
> Firebug panel, and you’ll see the complete DOM (including any HTML
> generated by JavaScript). Alternatively, you can use the Web Developer
> toolbar  in Firefox to view
> both the regular HTML source, and the generated HTML. • In IE 9, press
> the F12 key to open the Developer Tools panel, then click the HTML tab
> to see the page’s HTML. In the case of IE9, the HTML tab starts by
> showing the downloaded HTML (the same as the View Source command). But
> if you click the refresh icon (or press F5), the HTML tab shows the
> rendered HTML complete with any JavaScript-created changes. • In
> Chrome, select View→Developer→Developer Tools and click the Elements
> tab in the panel at the bottom of the browser window. • In Safari,
> make sure the Developer menu is on (choose Safari→Preferences, click
> the Advanced button, and make sure the “Show Develop menu in menu bar”
> is checked. Then open the page you’re interested in looking at, and
> choose Develop→Show Web Inspector. Click the Elements tab in the panel
> that appears at the bottom of the browser window. • In Opera, choose
> Tools→Advanced→Opera Dragonfly. (Dragonfly is the name of Opera’s
> built-in set of developer tools.) In the panel that appears at the
> bottom of the browser window, click the Documents tab.

so the **scraper** won't download the page after the JavaScript finished it will get what it looks before any the JavaScript manipulation

you can watch  Michael Schrenk talking about Screen Scraper Tricks: Extracting Data from Difficult Websites

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtffxCi8aq4

Comment: Thank you, this help me so much, beside all of this I found easy trick, just to download the webpage as html on your PC, it will include all data, then to parse it.

Comment: This will help if you want to parse data locally after using a browser to download it